# Deployment and DB script running via post deployment web hook

Tags: php, database, wordpress, svn, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using svn / Beanstalk for deployment website (of a wordpress site) to a staging environment (but I don't think this is necessarily a beanstalk issue)

The process is currently able to update all the files from our subversion server, but we also need to be able to update the server's database.

I know Beanstalk can run a post deployment web hook, where it could run a php file after deploying files.

My thought was that we could check in a sql script of the changed tables, and have the post hook fire off a php script that reads in that sql file and updates tables as needed.

Does anyone have any examples of post deploy web hooks doing database changes?

Or is there a better way to apply database changes to a deployed (wordpress) server?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing php script, just like you mentioned and running this script with a [Container_command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) command. Let me know if you still need samples and I'll post one.